# Is there a good way to extend a class with additional operators?

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

I have been missing some important functionality from `std::complex` like the ability to add a `std::complex<float>` and a `std::complex<double>` or operations like `1+c`, i.e. between `int` and `std::complex`. My idea was to derive a new class `my::complex` from `std::complex` which just inherits everything that is already implemented and adds other stuff.

In order to make the code compatible with functions using `std::complex`, I added automatic conversion to and from `std::complex` (and also automatic conversions between `my::complex<float>` and `my::complex<double>`).

Now something like

```
my::complex<float> c1,c2,c3;
c1 = c2 + c3;
```

works even though I did not implement `operator+` myself, since `c2` and `c3` are cast to `std::complex`, added and the result is cast back to `my::complex`. I am assuming that the compiler can optimize any actual copying away.

However, the following does not work:

```
c1 = 2*(c2+c3)
```

since `std::complex` can not be multiplied by an integer (same problem if I multiply by a double and have `complex<float>`s).

I thought "ok, it seems that I have to add `operator+` after all", but if I do that, I get `use of overloaded operator '+' is ambiguous` since the compiler can between `std::complex` and `my::complex` implicitly.

Is there a better way to achieve what I want or do I need to completely reimplement everything in `std::complex` and throw out the inheritance?

Comment: not sure but did you try `c1 = (c2+c3)*2` ?

Comment: again not sure, but to add `std::complex<float>` to `std::complex<double>` I think you do not need inheritance, but you can implement the operator as a free function

Comment: Automatic type conversion is the worst, most dangerous misfeature of C++, which is why conversion constructors are `explicit` in `std::complex`. Swim against the current at your own risk.

Comment: @n.m. I see you're a shill for keyboard companies trying to make everyone wear out their keyboards so they have to buy more.  Syntax is an important part of a usable language and implicit type conversions are an important part of making dense yet readable code.

Comment: @xaxxon it is actually my mistake, only narrowing conversions are explicit. Anyway, `operator+` and the like don't consider implicit conversions either, so mixed-type arithmetic is not allowed, which is a good thing IMHO.  If you disagree, talk to the standards committee first, then to me.

Answer (score 7):

Adding these overloads as free functions is probably about as good a way to do the job as any. I wouldn't, however, write a separate one hard-coded for each possible pair of operand types--that would get tedious very quickly.

Instead, you undoubtedly want to write a template function to handle any pair of operand types. Something on this general order:

```
template <class T, class U>
auto operator*(T const &a, U const &b) -> typename std::common_type<T, U>::type 
{
    // code to produce the equivalent of: return a * b;
}
```

This way if you multiply a `complex<double>` by an `int` and a `complex<float>` by a `double` (etc.) you don't have to duplicate the function for each possible combination (and if you try to combine two types that don't have a common type such as `complex<double>` and `std::string`, it simply won't compile).

In this case, filling in the body is fairly simple: we have inputs of two different types, but we know (or can deduce) a common type that's compatible with both. We want to cast each input to that common type, and do the operation on the results from casting:

```
template <class T, class U>
auto operator*(T const &a, U const &b) -> typename std::common_type<T, U>::type 
{
    using ret_type = typename std::common_type<T, U>::type;
    return ret_type(a) * ret_type(b);
}
```

Comment: I feel a bit ashamed for my answer now ;)

Comment: Arent you implementing the operator a*b in terms of itself? How is that supposed to work?

Comment: @MikeMB: Sorry, I guess I didn't state it, but the body was only intended to be basically pseudo-code as a place-holder. That is to say, in there you'd do whatever's needed to multiply the two items, and return the result. I've edited to make that more apparent, and add an actual implementation.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand how this works, but how do std::complex<double> and int have a common type?
Also, I don't know the -> syntax in this case. Is this C++11 specific? I cannot use that in my code unfortunately

Comment: @ViktorDick: yes, the trailing return type is specific to C++11. Quite  a bit of what this uses was added in C++11. If you really need to get by without C++11 (why?) Boost probably has rough equivalents that will work with older compilers (e.g., if memory serves, they had a `common_type` well before it was added to the standard).

Comment: @ViktorDick: As for there being a common type between `complex<double>` and `int`, it's pretty simple: `common_type` basically finds a type to which both can be converted (restricted to implicit conversions unless `common_type` has been specialized to do otherwise).

Answer (score 6):

For adding complex numbers of different types and other operators I would use free functions

```
std::complex<double> operator? (std::complex<double> a,std::complex<float> b){
    std::complex<double> result;
    // implement ?
    return result;
}
std::complex<double> operator? (std::complex<float> a,std::complex<double> b){
    return b ? a;
}
```

where `?` is a placehold for the operator you want to have. Note that this is a pre-C++11 solution, for a much nicer way see [Jerry Coffins answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37496825/4117728).

For adding a number to a complex, like in `1+c`, I would not make the effort to write an operator, but simply use `c+1` instead (actually I am not sure if this works for `std::complex` but I would be surprised if not).

Comment: `c+1` and `1+c` are both not defined if `c` is `complex<double>`. They are both defined if `c` is `complex<int>`.